# DDD: placement of method whose behavior may be implemented with single database query

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design

Let's say we have `Book` entity in our library. A requirement says:

> Librarian may disable 'available' flag to books published before some year. For example, librarian may 'hide' some old books from being publicly available as they are rare.

This behavior is easily done with single SQL command. The method name for this behavior may be e.g. `hideBooksPriorToYear()`.

But where to put this method?

- if we put it in the Repository, soon it will be full of such methods; moreover, this is a business method, not a repo method.
- we might fetch all old books and hide one by one, but this is slow.
- we might create a business service for that, but that looks like anemic model again
- we might put this method in a model, but I don't want to put sql there.

Any wisdom on this?

EDIT

Trying to clarify. When I try to move behavior to the entities methods, I found out that most of the business is not available without a repo. And I do not want to inject repo instance into the models. So my entities soon starts to be: 1) simple data objects, and 2) factories for entities/aggregates that are related to the model.

Comment: This could be a static method on `Book`, since it does not apply to a specific book in this case. But it sounds like the architecture could use some work first: ideally, SQL is separated from your domain models since it is implementation-specific. You should be able to swap out one SQL database for another or for NoSQL or a flat file without affecting your data models.

Comment: Yeah, and in that sense it belongs to Service... and I am afraid soon we have a lot of such methods. I just can't see how I can decouple repo from the models in some cases.

Comment: Perhaps there's a new concept to unearth here. Do libraries have "Book Visibility Policies"?

Comment: @Darien nice, we might use [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). In that case, our policies are executed on Repo? btw, there is often a significant number of similar commands that could be executed with few sqls. Does this means we should use policies for them? (you may elaborate in an answer ;)

Comment: Whoever vote this down, should better explain.

Comment: When this operation is run, how many books would be affected by it? tens? hundreds? thousands? more?

Comment: @Pete how does this matters - this is just an example, so some methods may operate on few, some on more then a few.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your particular case, as a rule of thumb, methods which operate on a single entity should be defined on the model itself, whilst those methods which operate on the entity collection as a whole should be defined on the service.

Methods such as `getLatest`, `getMostPopular`, `getOutOfStock`, `deleteFromPublisher`, `deleteFromAuthor` are all ideal candidates for being defined on the service in your architecture, since such queries would inspect all existing entities.

To contrast, methods such as `delete`, `hide`, `setStock`, `setPrice` should ideally be defined on the model itself, since you would utilize these on a particular entity which you have in the current context.

Your concern that you might end up with a lot of such methods on the service is subjective. From the perspective of maintenance, there are ways to deal with this should it become unbearable, but it still doesn't change the fact that these should be qualified from the service object itself.

Comment: Even `delete()`?

Comment: Depends on how the persistence plumbing is designed, but yes, there are some naked designs circulating in the wild which have this implementation. Observe the use of class and instance methods which discriminate operations on the whole collection or a single entity: `new Book(data).save()` and `Book.create(data)`; in such a design, you would use  `book.delete()` instead of something like `Books.delete(book)`. See this for an example https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#creating-objects.

Comment: In case of `book.delete()`, wouldn't the entity `Book` contain a reference to the repository?

Comment: Yes, exactly! Dynamically typed languages have sophisticated reflective capabilities and statically typed languages can make use of dependency injection and factories to facilitate this reference. Aside from anemic models, Fowler also conceptualized the Active Record pattern and it's implementations are still evolving. This approach twines all those different designs to be exposed on the entity's resulting type, and instances of, for service-like operations. Essentially, your entity is fully aware it is persisted in some data store and part of a collection.

Comment: I would just like to add that having these smart entities lends itself to the resulting design. If you can reuse their behavior and transform these additional objects as intrinsic features of an entity, your entities would literally sit directly on top of the repositories, since the services, their repository client and other delegates are literally inlined and no longer a member of your DDD. This would allow you to fully focus on the business requirements.

Comment: Hey @Filip Dupanović, I thought that it is not longer practice to inject Repos into the Model. In that sense, why would the model know that it will be stored? Moreover, what happens when book saves itself - where is the transactional boundary? is the whole aggregate saved? Isn't that maybe too smart for model to know all about that? In other words, is the saving itself a domain behavior? (Don't get me wrong, just trying to understand everything you said ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18328/discussion-between-filip-dupanovic-and-lawpert).